# Get specific edge with boost::graph

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm using `boost::graph` and I have two `vertex_descriptor`s. What is the quickest way to get the edge between them, without iterating over all the edges?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Ok, I found it out. `boost::edge(u,v,g)` returns `pair<edge_descriptor, bool>` where the `bool` is whether the edge exists. So in my case I know it does, so I use the expression:

```
boost::edge(u,v,g).first
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `boost::edge(u,v,g).second`, if you want the `bool` value...

Comment: @tnull since I know the edge exists and I'm looking for the edge itself, `first` is the attribute I need.

Answer (score 7):

There is also a function `boost::lookup_edge()` in `boost/graph/lookup_edge.hpp`; that function dispatches to either `edge()` or `out_edges()` and a search based on the particular graph type you are using.